# Log4j is not writing the log into the file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

**Log4j.xml**

```
  <appender name="U_R_A" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="fatal" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="File" value="/logs/log_file.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout" />
   </appender>

  <logger name="U_Q_R" additivity="false">
    <!-- Overridding from fatal to error -->
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="U_R_A" />
  </logger>
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main{
  private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("U_Q_R");
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml"); 
    logger.error("Some error happened!!");
  }
}
```

Log4j is not writing the error into the file **log_file.log**.
If I change the Threshold into **error**, then it is writing the content into the file. Please help me to understand.

Comment: see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653548/log4j-priority-value-and-param-name-concept-explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the logger has level `ERROR`, it won't overwrite the appender's threshold.

Log messages with `>= ERROR` will be accepted by the logger, since  you have defined level as `ERROR`. Then your logger has only one appender defined, with threshold `fatal`, which means the appender will handle logs with level `>=fatal`. that's why `error` level logs won't be saved in your log file.

when you changed the `threshold <= logger's level`, all logs accepted by your logger will be handled by the appender. That's why it "worked" if you change the threshold into `error`.