# log4j2 threshold for consoleappender

Tags: log4j2, threshold

How to set threshold value for ConsoleAppender in new log4j2 using xml file.
Usually we do it in log4j 1.x in the below way.

Ref link:
[Log4j - priority value and param name concept explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653548/log4j-priority-value-and-param-name-concept-explanation/8994413#8994413)

How to set it in log4j 2.x ?

Answer (score 9):

You can set a log level on the AppenderRef:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="warn"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter to replace the

```
<param name="Threshold" value="trace" />
```

with

```
<Filter type="ThresholdFilter" level="trace"/>
```