# How can I change the AppenderRef Level in log4j2 programmatically?

Tags: java, log4j2

How can I change the `AppenderRef` `Level` in log4j2?

There is a  [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427352/) (with answer) where this was solved non-programmatically. I want the same but programmatically instead. There is only a get method in `AppenderRef` to retrieve the `Level` but no method to set it.

So, is there any way to set the `Level` in the `AppenderRef` in log4j2 programmatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to do it by removing the appender and then adding it again with the desired level.

**Example `log4j2.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="logFile" fileName="log.txt" immediateFlush="false"
              append="true">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="logFile" level="info"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Example code:**

```java
package example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig;

public class Log4j2SetAppenderRefLvlMain {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();

        
        log.info("Before altering the appender!");
        
        LoggerConfig rootLoggerConfig = config.getLoggers().get("");
        rootLoggerConfig.removeAppender("logFile");
        rootLoggerConfig.addAppender(config.getAppender("logFile"), Level.WARN, null);
        ctx.updateLoggers();
        
        log.info("After altering the appender!");
        log.warn("After altering the appender!");
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
2017-04-13 21:04:20.892 [main] INFO  example.Log4j2SetAppenderRefLvlMain - Before altering the appender!
2017-04-13 21:04:20.895 [main] WARN  example.Log4j2SetAppenderRefLvlMain - After altering the appender!
```

Notice how only the `WARN` level message is printed to the log after we changed the appender level to `WARN`. This proves that it works.

Comment: does not seems to work with the latest version of log4j2